# Adding controller with Entity Framework failed - DbContext Error

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a .Net Core app with EntityFramework.
I wanted to add controller with CRUD operations.
But I got this error
[image]

I don't get any error while performing add-migration. It finds only one DbContext.

These are all the places where I have WebApplication8Context

**WEBAPPLICATION8CONTEXT.CS**

```
    namespace WebApplication8.Data
{
    public class WebApplication8Context : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public WebApplication8Context(DbContextOptions<WebApplication8Context> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
     

        public DbSet<Tasks> Tasks { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TaskGroups> TaskGroups { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
            // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
            // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        }
    }
```

**IDENTITYHOSTINGSTARTUP.CS**

```
    [assembly: HostingStartup(typeof(WebApplication8.Areas.Identity.IdentityHostingStartup))]
namespace WebApplication8.Areas.Identity
{
    public class IdentityHostingStartup : IHostingStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
                services.AddDbContext<WebApplication8Context>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(
                        context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("WebApplication8ContextConnection")));

                services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<WebApplication8Context>();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**APPSETTINGS.JSON**

```
    {
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "WebApplication8ContextConnection": "Server=CREATIVESM\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MarApplication;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
}
```

**BEGGINING OF MY WEBAPPLICATION8MODELSNAPSHOT**

```
    namespace WebApplication8.Migrations
{
    [DbContext(typeof(WebApplication8Context))]
    partial class WebApplication8ContextModelSnapshot : ModelSnapshot
    {
        protected override void BuildModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
#pragma warning disable 612, 618
            modelBuilder
                .HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "3.1.10")
                .HasAnnotation("Relational:MaxIdentifierLength", 128)
                .HasAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);
```

**My Startup.cs**

```
    namespace WebApplication8
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Other places where I can find WebApplication8Context are my migrations.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is a conflict between `IdentityHostingStartup` and `Startup`.

Although I don't know the specific reason, you can use the following methods to solve it:

You can delete the code in your `IdentityHostingStartup`,then add it to your `Startup` like this:

```
    services.AddDbContext<WebApplication8Context>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("WebApplication8ContextConnection")));
    services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<WebApplication8Context>();
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddRazorPages();
```

Re-migration and update database,then you will add the controller successful.

Comment: Adding code to startup instead of identityhostingstartup worked :) thank you!